# getting 500.30 error after restart app service in azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

after I restarted my app service I getting 500.30 error and I am new to AZURE services any tutorials or articles that helps I really would appreciate that

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) You need to provide more details of your problem so that you can get appropriate answers. what is the app you have deployed, which language it is implemented? Is it working fine in your local machine?

Answer (score 3):

Based on our investigations , we have understood that Http status code 500.30 occurs in .Net core web applications.

- Http 500.30 status code occurs when The worker process fails. The app doesn't start.
- The [ASP.NET Core Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-3.1) attempts to start the .NET Core CLR in-process, but it fails to start. The cause of a process startup failure can usually be determined from entries in the Application Event Log and the ASP.NET Core Module stdout log.

To know more information about the error Go to Azure Portal > your App Service > under development tools open console. We can run the application through this console and thus visualize the real error that is causing our application not to load. For that put, the name of our project followed by “.exe” and press the enter key.

[image]

please refer these documents for more information about  [500.30 In-Process Startup Failure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.1#50030-in-process-startup-failure) & for [Troubleshooting  on Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.1#troubleshoot-on-azure-app-service).

Comment: This was so incredibly helpful to me.